# How can I update path prefix attribute of data tag in intent filter in android manifest from activity?

Tags: android

This is the manifest's snippet. I want to pass string to query parameter 'id' in pathPrefix from the activity. How do I do that?

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <data android:scheme="http" android:host="www.myHost.com" android:pathPrefix="/video?id="/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: Are you intending for this to trigger when the user touches a deep link?

Comment: Yeah. I want to start this activity when the link will be clicked. I am able to parse the uri in the activity, but I want to change pathprefix every time according to users activity on other activities.

Comment: hmm, I'm not sure you can achieve that. The way the deep links work is that   you can setup this activity to be launched when a link is pressed that matches the form: http://www.myHost.com/video but I don't think you can have query parameters in it.

Comment: Have you taken a look at: https://developer.android.com/training/app-indexing/deep-linking.html?

`<!-- Accepts URIs that begin with "http://www.example.com/gizmos” -->
        <data android:scheme="http"
              android:host="www.example.com"
              android:pathPrefix="/gizmos" />`

Comment: Yep. Read that also. I've successfully implemented my custom query parameter like 'video?id=Zi_XLOBDo_Y', and fetched this param in the activity.

Comment: You Can Pass json into Id with id and query parameters .Inst end of sending only one id.

Comment: Wish I could. But these ids are fetched from some APIs.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I've solved the problem using

```
android:pathPattern="/.*"
```

in data tag, in place of pathPrefix, and fetching query as:

```
Uri uri = intent.getData();
String videoId = uri.getQueryParameter("id");
```